# Visual Studio variables unused (4101) sometimes has no warning

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

When I define an unused variable in visual studio (2017 & 2019), I'm getting inconsistent warnings.  Primitives and instances of classes I create seem to always give the warning while stl containers like `std::vector` do not get warnings. What could be causing this and is there a way to ensure the warning appears on stl containers?

For example,

```
// this creates a warning
void foo()
{
    int my_int;
}

// this does not create a warning
void bar()
{
    std::vector<int> my_vec;
}
```

Comment: It's not a matter of standard library types. Compare: https://godbolt.org/z/ddv9Kobso. It seems to be a matter of _"triviality"_ of involved initialization/destruction.

Answer (score 0):

When declaring stl variables, the default constructor is called. Therefore, VS takes it as if they *are*, in fact, used. So, VS only gives you the warning if you do *nothing* but declaring (and assigning value) to a variable. As mentioned in a comment, it's all about initialization and destruction.